# Get keyboard macro mapping

Tags: keyboard-macros

What functionality is available in emacs to get information about a keyboard macro?

Even something as simple as printing out what the macro evaluates.

Comment: What have you tried, and in which way did this not give you the info you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

In *general* terms you can't really say what a keyboard macro does without executing it, because it's all contextual.  What does `C-c C-c` do?  It depends.  What does `C-x o C-c C-c` do?  That depends on even more things (like the window configuration you happen to have at the time).

However... if you invoke the keyboard macro editor, it'll do the best it can to show you which commands the keys are going to call.  It might be wrong about them, because the context available in the editor may not be the context in which you use the macro; but if your macro is pretty generic, you'll at least have a good idea.

Use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to edit a keyboard macro.